# Building from and uploading to a local Python repository without writing credentials to disk

Tags: python, artifactory, setuptools

I have a Python build pipeline set up, with a Jfrog Artifactory Python repository serving our internal packages.

The pipeline uses this repository to resolve internal dependencies and upload build artefacts.

This is currently done with `python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist upload -r local`. This command actually requires the credentials to be on disk *twice*; once for resolving local dependencies via ~/.pydistutils.cfg:

```
[easy_install]
index_url=https://username:password@artifactory/api/repo/path/simple
```

...and again in ~/.pypirc for uploading the build package:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = local

[local]
repository: https://artifactory/api/repo/path
username: build_agent
password: ****
```

For security reasons I would like the username and password to never touch the disk. We already have a secure way of injecting secrets into the build environment from (Hashicorp) Vault, and I'd like to leverage this for the Artifactory credentials.

However, while I can set PIP_INDEX_URL for installing packages with pip, there is no equivalent for setuptools that I can see. Without these files defined, the command `python setup.py sdist` results in a stack trace the following error:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('local-package==0.0.3')
```

Clearly, it is attempting to resolve a local dependency on public pypi, which is undesirable for a number of reasons (the local repository proxies pypi, so we should never read public pypi to prevent hijacking).

Essentially then my question is; **how can I build and upload a python package, which has dependencies in a local repository, to that local repository, using credentials that are in environment variables and not in ~/.pypirc or ~/.pydistutils.cfg?**

### Additional background

The original implementation baked .pypirc and .pydistutils.cfg in the build agent AMI, which is built with Packer.

The problem with this, is that the username and password for the repository is essentially readable in plain text by anyone with access to the AWS account and the ability to download or create a new instance using the image.

That's easy, just add a build step which sets up pypirc before starting the build you say! I would like to avoid this approach, because it is brittle in the sense that it creates a global run-time build dependency. In future, someone could setup a job assuming the config files have already been created without doing so themselves, and it will almost always work because another job has run first. I can't remove the file after each build, because there could be concurrent builds requiring the file to be present.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but it's not particularly pretty.

First problem is `setup_requires`. Because it calls easy_install so early in the process, it's difficult to override; even creating a Distribution subclass and overriding the `fetch_egg` method didn't help. The workaround I've settled on for now is to wrap the setup method and preinstall them via pip (with `PIP_INDEX_URL` set):

```
from setuptools import setup

def _setup(**kwargs):
    requires = kwargs.get('setup_requires') or []

    for req in requires:
        pip.main(['install', req])

    return setup(**kwargs)


_setup(
    name='mypackage',
    ...
)
```

This is only needed for packages that specify local dependencies in setup_requires, and `python setup.py install` remains broken. As pip does the installation in tox (`deps = .[test]` in the `[testenv]` section) and never use setup.py to install, a broken install command isn't a problem.

The second problem was uploading. Rather than do the upload with setup.py upload, I'm shifting this task to [twine](https://github.com/pypa/twine). Recent versions of twine read TWINE_USERNAME, TWINE_PASSWORD, and TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL from the environment if they are not in the traditional config files.

Anyway, I would love to find a more elegant solution to the first problem, especially one that didn't leave setup.py install broken, but for now this will do.

Comment: Did you manage to get twine to work with an Artifactory Python repo? I'd like to use it for the same reason, but Artifactory rejects my pushes with HTTP 400 and the message `"No enum constant org.jfrog.repomd.pypi.model.PypiMetadata.MetadataVersion.v2_1"`

Comment: Yep, twine worked fine for me. The problem you describe sounds like Artifactory not supporting the metadata of the package you're uploading. Make sure you're running the latest version of Artifactory; otherwise you'll have to find a way to build packages with an older metadata format (I achieved this by downgrading setuptools IIRC). This ticket references the problem for an older format: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12710

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Artifactory 6.6, so not the latest but not ancient. Pinning `setuptools<38.5.2` does the trick actually, it seems 38.5.2 onwards will use metadata 2.1. Which setuptools are you on? If you're more recent and it's working then it must be fixed in Artifactory but I can't find a mention on the ticket or release notes. Without knowing for definite that this is fixed, it might be hard to justify upgrading the instance.

Comment: It's been about a year since I last looked at this, but turns out I pinned at the exact same setuptools version, 38.5.2. We use the SaaS version of artifactory, so it's updated automatically.

Comment: Ahhh that explains it then. I think that's our best option for now.